# Html Input=text performs postback when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, signalr

I am using SignalR to make a chat and it works but when someone enters some text and presses `return` it performs a postback and then all previous chat is lost and no message is sent. My primary goal is to avoid it performing this postback but ideally it would call the send button click event.

I have tried to make a javascript function on keypressed so it should cancel the postback but that did not change anything. I have also tried to change it into an `asp:TextBox` with the AutoPostback attribute set to false.

My current code:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send"/>
    <ul id="discussion">
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (time, name, message) {
        // Html encode display time, name, and message. 
        var encodedTime = $('<div />').text(time).html();
        var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
        var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
        // Add the message to the page. 
        $('#discussion').append('<li>[' + encodedTime +'] ' + encodedName
            + ': ' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
        // Set initial focus to message input box.  
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                chat.server.send($('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Assuming there is a <form> tag somewhere in there, adding onSubmit="return false;" should prevent it from posting.

Comment: Is this your whole code ?

Comment: It is the code inside the main ContentPlaceHolder of a standard asp.net website (the one it creates when choosing asp.net web forms application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your HTML is wrapped by a `<form>`. You should be able to prevent any postbacks by adding the following to your JS:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You might want to make the selector more specific of course.